# base R: How to add row titles to a 2 x 2 figure

Tags: r, plot

I have a 2 x 2 figure where the columns represent two different variables and the rows represent two different locations. How can I add the names of the two locations to the two rows?

Example Data

```
library(biwavelet)

par(mfrow = c(2,2),
    oma = c(3,3,0,0) + 0.1,
    mar = c(1,1,1,1) + 0.1)

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 500, ncol = 2))

dat[1] <- seq(1,500)
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1])

# top-left figure
plot(wt(dat),
     xaxt = 'n',
     xlab = "",
     cex.axis = 1.5,
     cex.lab = 1.5)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 0.1, col.axis = 'NA')
title("Variable 1", line = 0.1, cex.main = 1.5)

# top-right figure
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1]*.5)
plot(wt(dat),
     xaxt = 'n',
     col.axis = 'NA',
     xlab = "",
     ylab = "")
axis(1, at = seq(0, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 0.1, col.axis = 'NA')
title("Variable 2", line = 0.1, cex.main = 1.5)

# bottom-left figure
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1]*.25)
plot(wt(dat),
     cex.axis = 1.5)

# bottom-right figure
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1]*.125)
plot(wt(dat),
     col.axis = 'NA',
     ylab = "",
     xlab = "")
axis(1, at = seq(0, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 1.5)

title(xlab = "Time (hours)",
      ylab = "Period",
      outer = TRUE,
      line = 1.5,
      cex.lab = 1.5)
```

The ideal figure would look like this
[image]

Comment: `mtext()` is commonly used to add text in margins to a figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the suggested solutions so far have put the right-hand labels in the orientation requested. You cannot do so with `mtext`, but rather need to use `text`, first allowing `text` to display outside the plot region with `par(xpd=NA)`. (See `?text` and `?par`, where one reads that the `srt`,rotation, parameter only applies to `text`):

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), xpd=FALSE)
par(mar = c(1,1,1,1) + 2)
plot(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
mtext("disp 1", side=3)
plot(I(2*disp) ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
mtext("disp 2", side=3); par(xpd=NA)
text("mpg 1",  x=36, y=500, srt=270)
plot(disp ~ I(2*mpg), data = mtcars); par(xpd=NA)
plot(I(2*disp) ~ I(2*mpg), data = mtcars)
text("mpg 2",  x=72, y=500, srt=270)
```

It is not as automatic as `mtext` in the sense that one needs to look at each plotting figure separately to derive a estimate for the x and y positions in the plotting coordinates.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method:

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
par(mar = c(1,1,1,1) + 0.1)
plot(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
mtext("disp 1", side=3)
plot(I(2*disp) ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
mtext("disp 2", side=3)
mtext("mpg 1", side=4)
plot(disp ~ I(2*mpg), data = mtcars)
plot(I(2*disp) ~ I(2*mpg), data = mtcars)
mtext("mpg 2", side=4)
```

[image: base graphics plot, 2x2 grid]

Unfortunately, `mtext` does not support rotating text, so you're stuck with the right labels being oriented as they are.

Comment: This is helpful. Hard to believe that there is not a way to rotate the text though. Can margin text only be added with ```mtext()```?

Comment: It's the easiest, to be frank. You can use `text(..., xpd=NA)` or similar, though while `mtext` is a lot more oriented to add "lines" of information on a side, `text` is based on the user-dimensions, meaning if your axis scales from 1 to 1e6, then you may need `text(-50000, ...)`, but if it scales from 0 to 0.001, then perhaps `text(-0.0000001, ...)`, and this is sensitive to how much expansion the plotting function does to the limits. As you might imagine, there are corner-cases that make this a bit more problematic than simple algebra should be.

Comment: It's too bad that `biwavelet` doesn't support grid/ggplot2 ...

Comment: @tassones: See my answer re; "is there another way to rotate text".

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this page, the code I ended up using was based on @IRTFM answer, see below. It was challenging finding the appropriate `y =`  in the `text()` function. I used an iterative approach and found the `y =`  to be much lower than I anticipated.

```
library(biwavelet)

par(mfrow = c(2,2), xpd=F)
par(mar = c(1,1,1.1,1.1) + 0.1,
    oma = c(3,3,0.5,0.5) + 0.1)

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 500, ncol = 2))

dat[1] <- seq(1,500)
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1])

# top-left figure
plot(wt(dat),
     xaxt = 'n',
     xlab = "",
     cex.axis = 1.5,
     cex.lab = 1.5)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 1.5, col.axis = 'NA')
mtext("Variable 1", side = 3, cex = 1.5, line = 0.1)
box(lty = "solid", col = 'black')

# top-right figure
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1]*.5)
plot(wt(dat),
     xaxt = 'n',
     col.axis = 'NA',
     xlab = "",
     ylab = "")
axis(1, at = seq(100, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 0.1, col.axis = 'NA')
mtext("Variable 2", side = 3, cex = 1.5, line = 0.1)
text("Location 1", x = 520, y = 4.1, srt = 270, cex = 1.5, xpd=NA)
box(lty = "solid", col = 'black')

# bottom-left figure
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1]*.25)
plot(wt(dat),
     cex.axis = 1.5,
     xlab = "",
     ylab = "")
axis(1, at = seq(100, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 1.5)
box(lty = "solid", col = 'black')

# bottom-right figure
dat[2] <- sin(dat[1]*.125)
plot(wt(dat),
     col.axis = 'NA',
     ylab = "",
     xlab = "")
axis(1, at = seq(100, 500, by = 100), cex.axis = 1.5)
text("Location 2", x = 520, y = 4.5, srt = 270, cex = 1.5, xpd=NA)
box(lty = "solid", col = 'black')

title(xlab = "Time (hours)",
      ylab = "Period",
      outer = TRUE,
      line = 1.5,
      cex.lab = 1.5)
```

[image]